# for loop/if statement working around referencing non existent cell in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame I need to loop , and specify new column values based on the value of the row corresponding to my counter and the next row. My problem is doing this for the last row breaks the loop.

What I'd like it to do if no [j+1] row exists than just apply the criteria to the row I do have, e.g. at row 10 in this code, evaluate if it's bigger than 8, if so make biggerthan8ornext[10] = "YES"

```
set.seed(2)
c <- rnorm (mean=10,sd=3, n=10)
a<- 1:10
ac<- as.data.frame (cbind(a,c))

for (j in 1:10){
  if (!(ac$c[j]<8|ac$c[j+1]<8)) ac$biggerthan8hereornext[j] <- "YES"
  else
    ac$biggerthan8hereornext[j] <- "NO"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can just add an additional `else if` statement that checks for the number of rows explicitly:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(ac)){
    if (ac$c[j] > 8) 
        ac$biggerthan8hereornext[j] <- "YES"
    else if (nrow(ac) > j && ac$c[j+1] > 8)
        ac$biggerthan8hereornext[j] <- "YES"
    else
        ac$biggerthan8hereornext[j] <- "NO"
}
```

However, this seems clunky. A nicer R way is to vectorise the comparison:

```
## Create two vectors
## Remove the first element of c2 and pad out with FALSE
c1 = ac$c > 8
c2 = c((ac$c > 8)[-1], FALSE)
```

Then

```
ac$better = "No"
ac$better[c1 & c2] = "Yes"
ac    

R> ac
    a      c biggerthan8hereornext better
1   1  7.309                    NO     No
2   2 10.555                   YES    Yes
3   3 14.764                    NO     No
4   4  6.609                    NO     No
5   5  9.759                   YES    Yes
6   6 10.397                   YES    Yes
7   7 12.124                   YES    Yes
8   8  9.281                   YES    Yes
9   9 15.953                   YES    Yes
10 10  9.584                    NO     No
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you always know how many rows there are, via `arows<- nrow(ac)`, just set your loop to `for(j in 1:arows))`, and if you require a bigger output matrix, then

`for (k in 1:(N-arows)) cbind(ac,ac[arows,])`